# Add a proper FileDialog with Browse PushButton in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qfiledialog

I wrote the following code in order to do some calculations. I want to add a Widget like the small picture such that when I click on pushbutton I can browse a CSV file and that path is shown in a LineEdite. I need to have this Widger in the Experiment Info QGroupBox below the checkBox.  But I do not know how to add all these 3 Widget in one row in this group box.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QAction, QMenu, QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Application(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('File')
        run = menubar.addMenu('Run')
        exit = menubar.addMenu('Exit')

        impMenu = QMenu('Import', self)
        impAct = QAction('Import mail', self)
        impMenu.addAction(impAct)

        newAct = QAction('New', self)

        fileMenu.addAction(newAct)
        fileMenu.addMenu(impMenu)

        # ------------- Layout ---------------------------
        wid =QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(wid)
        mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        config_box = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("Configuration")
        info_box = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("Info Box")

        # ------------- Config Box Layut -----------------
        Config_Box_Layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()


        case_box = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("case")

        operations_box = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("Operations")

        Config_Box_Layout.addWidget(case_box, 0, 0)
        Config_Box_Layout.addWidget(operations_box, 0, 1)

        # ----------- Operations-----------------------
        operation_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        op1 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('Add')
        op2= QtWidgets.QCheckBox('Multiplication')

        operation_layout.addWidget(op1)
        operation_layout.addWidget(op2)
        # ----------- cases -----------------------
        case_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        _1 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("1")
        _2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("2")
        _3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("3")

        case_layout.addWidget(_1)
        case_layout.addWidget(_2)
        case_layout.addWidget(_3)


        # --------- Info Box LayOut -----------------------
        Info_box_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        exp_input_grou = QtWidgets.QGroupBox('Experiment Info')
        exp_input_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        version_input = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        version_input.addItem("Algo Version")
        version_input.addItem("V53")
        version_input.addItem("V52")
        version_input.addItem("V4")
        version_input.addItem("V3")

        nested_folder = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('Nested Data Path')

        dialog_file = QtWidgets.QFileDialog()

        pushB_ = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Browse')

        exp_input_layout.addWidget(version_input)
        exp_input_layout.addWidget(nested_folder)
        exp_input_layout.addWidget(pushB_)
        exp_input_layout.addWidget(dialog_file)


        exp_report = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        progres_bar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar()


        Info_box_layout.addWidget(exp_input_grou)
        Info_box_layout.addWidget(exp_report)
        Info_box_layout.addWidget(progres_bar)

        gt_path = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        gt_path.setFixedWidth(100)
        # -------- Adding Layouts ------------------------
        mainLayout.addWidget(config_box)
        config_box.setLayout(Config_Box_Layout)
        case_box.setLayout(case_layout)
        operations_box.setLayout(operation_layout)
        info_box.setLayout(Info_box_layout)
        exp_input_grou.setLayout(exp_input_layout)

        mainLayout.addWidget(info_box)
        wid.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 700)
        self.setWindowTitle('Example')
        app_icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        app_icon.addFile('pic.jpg', QtCore.QSize(256, 256))
        self.setWindowIcon(app_icon)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Application()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't see any "browse" button. Also, why are you trying to add a *dialog* to a layout?

Comment: I just added. I have to import some data from a path directory and therefore, I need to browse it.

Comment: Sorry but your request is still a bit confused. How the image you just added relates to your code? Do you want to add a line edit for the button and a browse button under the combobox? Is the file dialog used to *select* the path? Please, try to be more clear.

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. I change the question above. Yes, I need the same line of Widget in my Experiment Info Group Box below the checkBox.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add widgets horizontally in a vertical layout, you have to add an horizontal layout to it. This technique is generally referred to as "nested layouts".

Then, you don't have to create a file dialog instance within the init (otherwise it will be probably shown along with the main window), and you don't have to use the `QFileDialog()` constructor for your needs, since QDialog already provides [static methods](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#static-public-members) that easily allow you to open a standard dialog and get the selected file(s) or directory.

```
class Application(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        # ...

        # --------- Info Box LayOut -----------------------
        Info_box_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        exp_input_grou = QtWidgets.QGroupBox('Experiment Info')
        exp_input_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        version_input = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        version_input.addItem("Algo Version")
        version_input.addItem("V53")
        version_input.addItem("V52")
        version_input.addItem("V4")
        version_input.addItem("V3")

        nested_folder = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('Nested Data Path')

        # This should not be here!!!
        # dialog_file = QtWidgets.QFileDialog()

        exp_input_layout.addWidget(version_input)
        exp_input_layout.addWidget(nested_folder)

        browse_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        exp_input_layout.addLayout(browse_layout)

        self.gt_path = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

        pushB_ = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Browse')
        pushB_.clicked.connect(self.browse_path)

        browse_layout.addWidget(self.gt_path)
        browse_layout.addWidget(pushB_)

        # ...

    def browse_path(self):
        path, filter = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Select file', 
            '', 'CSV files (*.csv);;All files (*)')
        if path:
            self.gt_path.setText(path)
```

QGridLayout is also a valid alternative, but it doesn't work fine with everything, as its sizes are always dependent on the size of widgets each row or column contains. Your case is very simple, so it can be used without problems:

```
    def initUI(self):
        # ...

        # --------- Info Box LayOut -----------------------
        Info_box_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        exp_input_grou = QtWidgets.QGroupBox('Experiment Info')
        exp_input_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        version_input = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        version_input.addItem("Algo Version")
        version_input.addItem("V53")
        version_input.addItem("V52")
        version_input.addItem("V4")
        version_input.addItem("V3")

        nested_folder = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('Nested Data Path')

        self.gt_path = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        pushB_ = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Browse')
        pushB_.clicked.connect(self.browse_path)

        # add the combobox to the first row, first column, but set its column
        # span to 2, meaning that it occupies two "columns"
        exp_input_layout.addWidget(version_input, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        # the same for the checkbox, but on the second row
        exp_input_layout.addWidget(nested_folder, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        # add the line edit, third row, first column; if you don't specify the
        # span, the widget will only occupy one "cell" of the grid layout
        exp_input_layout.addWidget(self.gt_path, 2, 0)
        # and the button, same row, second column
        exp_input_layout.addWidget(pushB_, 2, 1)

        # ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The below code will do what you want, you just need to implement it into your code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(387, 224)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit.setReadOnly(True)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.open_file)

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 2, 1, 1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 387, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Select output file"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "..."))

    def open_file(self):
        self.file_name = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Open", "", "CSV Files (*.csv)")
        if self.file_name[0] != '':
            self.lineEdit.setText(self.file_name[0])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Editing the code generated by pyuic is not a good practice: it's something that *always* discouraged, and it also is not a good thing to use it for an example.

Comment: Ok, truth is that it looks more complicated than the traditional object-oriented approach but it has helped me to generate fast simple guis. I ve learned programming in PyQt5 using this method, so switching looks a bit difficult for me :p

Comment: I understand your point of view, but for the workflow of PyQt pyuic files should *never* be edited, but only used as imported modules (see [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html)). The most important reason for this is that programmers will often need to edit the gui multiple times after creating it, which might become a painful process to achieve if done when part of the logic has already been done. Also, here in SO we're trying to "fight" this approach as much as possible, as it's a very common source of problems that could be avoided otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for explaining to me why pyuic is not a good practice, i do appreciate it. Guess i have to learn to build my guis as a normal class.

Comment: Using pyuic files is not bad, you just have to leave those files as they are, never edit them and just import them as explained in the docs linked before. Alternatively you can use the `loadUi('file.ui', self)` function of the `PyQt5.uic` module, which will allow you to directly use the ui files created in Designer, so that the pyuic step can be avoided completely. I normally use this approach, as I believe it's much more easier and less prone to errors (sometimes you edit the ui but forget to rebuild the related py file). You're welcome, btw :-)